# Spans do not rotate when using mPDF

Tags: mpdf

```php
    $css  = '
        <style>

            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            div.titulos {
                height: 200px;
                background-color: #CCC;
            }

            div.registros {
                height: 30px;
                border-top: none;
            }

            div.titulos, 
            div.registros { 
                width: 870px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: thin solid #000;
            }

            div.titulos div, 
            div.registros div {
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-left: thin solid #000;
            }

            div.titulos div:nth-child(1), 
            div.registros div:nth-child(1) {
                border-left: none;
            }

            span {}

            span.normal {}

            span.rotate {
                height: 200px;
                rotate : -90;
                text-rotate : -90;
                writing-mode: vertical-rl;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
                transform-origin: center;
            }

        </style>
    ';

    $body = '   

    <div class="titulos">

        <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=normal>Nome do Gcéu</span></div>
        <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=rotate>Supervisor</span></div>
        <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=normal>Líder</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve Supervisão?</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve dia de Jejum?</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve dia de Evangelismo?</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Visitantes</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Crianças de 0 a 12 anos</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Total de presentes</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Ofertas</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Discipulados</span></div>
        <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Número de decisões</span></div>

    </div>

    <div class="registros">

        <div style="width: 100px;">Gceú</div>
        <div style="width: 100px;">Carlos</div>
        <div style="width: 100px;">Cleo</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">Sim</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">Sim</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">Não</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">12</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">3</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">3</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">18</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">12.3</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">2</div>
        <div style="width: 050px;">1</div>

    </div>  
    ';

    //echo $css.$body;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode( 'fullpage' );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $css, 1 );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $body );
    $mpdf->Output();
```

The code does not output correctly when output to PDF.

Here is an example screenshot of the PDF output:

[image: screenshot of pdf output]

Note that the span's `class=rotate`, but is not rotating. What can I change to fix this?

I need it works because it will be pressed when shown in the browser.

I've tried it with `rotate : -90;`, `text-rotate : -90;`, `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`, `transform: rotate(180deg);`, but none of these work. Why is that?

Comment: 180 degree rotate would put it back exactly where it started, shape-wise.

Comment: then, it's displayng with the figure!

Comment: sorry you commented too quick.  I edited my original comment.

Comment: no problem! But do you understand my problem? The spans not rotate!

Answer (score 1):

Property `text-rotate` is only supported for `tr`, `th` and `th` elements in mPDF.

`transform: rotate` is only supported on `img` element.

Also see [supported CSS documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html).

Comment: Ok. And in div elements. What i do?

Comment: Use a table :) Or a different library.